# correct pronoun to use with "person"

Tags: pronouns, singular-they

I was wondering what would be the right pronoun to use in this sentence:

> a person sees something that ... really likes

he, they, s/he ?

Comment: To avoid the criticism of *gender discrimination*, it has been a trend nowadays to use **they** (known as *singular they*). It's an example of 'grammaticality versus acceptability'.

Comment: @mahmudkoya Untrue. I don't know who told you it was ungrammatical, but they were wrong. It's been used as long as English has had modern pronouns. It's part of the pattern.

Comment: @mahmud koya Did you know that 'grammaticality' is ill-defined in English? A study by Quirk and Svartvik showed that (as one might expect) a panel of grammarians couldn't agree on how grammatical various sentences were. They proposed a gradience of grammaticality, with sentence 327 say turning out to be say 75% grammatical. Of course, using a different panel would have produced different results in some cases. The point is that we throw around the terms 'grammatical' and 'ungrammatical' as if that settles the issue.